# Mircscript on join on/off

Tags: scripting, mirc

I have this command for a onjoin event:

```
on !*:join:#:{ msg $chan MESSAGE }
```

How can i switch this message on/off by using example:

```
!onjoin on OR !onjoin off
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that indicate the status for this option. This variable will be set by the command you specified.

Script should be as follow:

```
on !*:join:#: if (%onJoinMessage) { msg # MESSAGE }
on *:text:!onjoin *:#: {
    if ($1 == on) { inc %onJoinMessage }
    elseif ($1 == off) { unset %onJoinMessage }
}
```